# C Memory Allocation For Dynamic char Pointer to chat Pointers Array

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, memcpy

The C script uses dirent to fetch directories and stores paths fetched and files:

```
// Packages
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// Constants
#define root "/"
#define currentDir "."
#define prevDir ".."
#define binDir "bin"
#define gitDir ".git"

// Structs
struct dirElements {
  int currentArrayDirectoryMaxElements;
  int currentArrayDirectoryElements;
  int currentArrayFileMaxElements;
  int currentArrayFileElements;
  const char **arrayDirectoriesPtr;
  const char **arrayFilesPtr;
};

/*
  concat concatenates two referenced strings,
  returns concatenated string or exit
*/
char *concat(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  // Create pointer to string with enough space for both one and null term.
  char *result = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1); // null term

  // If malloc fails exit with error
  if (result == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: failed to concatenate strings: %s and %s", s1, s2);

    exit(0);
  }

  // Copy first and second string in newly created pointer
  strcpy(result, s1);
  strcat(result, s2);
  return result;
}

/*
  increaseArraySize increases the size of a dynamic char pointer to pointers
  array
*/
const char **increaseArraySize(const char **arrayPtr,
                               int *currentMaxElementsPtr, int newMaxElements) {
  // Store
  int totalNewMaxElements = *currentMaxElementsPtr + newMaxElements;

  // Allocate space for enough elements
  const char **newSizeArray = malloc(totalNewMaxElements * sizeof(char *));

  if (newSizeArray == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: failed to allocate new array space");

    exit(0);
  }

  // Copy old array values into new array
  void *pointerDestination =
      memcpy((void *)newSizeArray, (const void *)arrayPtr,
              *currentMaxElementsPtr * sizeof(char *));

  printf("\n\nArray Passed in\n\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < *currentMaxElementsPtr; ++i) {
    printf("Old element: %s\n", arrayPtr[i]);
  };
  printf("\n\nNew Allocated Array\n\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < totalNewMaxElements; ++i) {
    printf("New element: %s\n", newSizeArray[i]);
  };
  printf("\n\n\n");

  // Update struct array pointer, max elements and free old array
  for (int i = 0; i < *currentMaxElementsPtr; ++i) {
    free((void *)arrayPtr[i]);
  }
  free((void *)arrayPtr);

  *currentMaxElementsPtr = totalNewMaxElements;
  return newSizeArray;
}

/*
  readDirAddFile recursively reads the passed in directory and adds each file to
  the dirElements struct passed as a reference.
*/
void readDirAddFile(const char *dirPath, struct dirElements *dirElementsStr) {
  // Fetch files and add their local dir path to array
  DIR *dir = opendir(dirPath);
  if (dir == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  // Read current directory
  struct dirent *entity = readdir(dir);

  // Create and allocate a string path to the current dir
  const char *pathToDir = concat(dirPath, (const char *)&root);

  // Iterate through all directory elements
  while (entity != NULL) {
    // File
    if (entity->d_type == DT_REG) {
      // Add file path to array
      const char *filePath = concat(pathToDir, (const char *)&entity->d_name);

      // Check if there is enough space for new file element, if not increase
      // size
      if (dirElementsStr->currentArrayFileMaxElements ==
          dirElementsStr->currentArrayFileElements) {
        dirElementsStr->arrayFilesPtr =
            increaseArraySize(dirElementsStr->arrayFilesPtr,
                              &dirElementsStr->currentArrayFileMaxElements, 15);
      }

      // Allocate Element
      dirElementsStr->arrayFilesPtr[dirElementsStr->currentArrayFileElements] =
          filePath;
      dirElementsStr->currentArrayFileElements += 1;
    }

    // Directory
    if (entity->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(entity->d_name, currentDir) != 0 &&
        strcmp(entity->d_name, prevDir) != 0 &&
        strcmp(entity->d_name, binDir) != 0 &&
        strcmp(entity->d_name, gitDir) != 0) {
      // Generate path
      const char *newDir = concat(pathToDir, (const char *)&entity->d_name);

      // Check if there is enough space for new directory element, if not
      // increase size
      if (dirElementsStr->currentArrayDirectoryMaxElements ==
          dirElementsStr->currentArrayDirectoryElements) {
        dirElementsStr->arrayDirectoriesPtr = increaseArraySize(
            dirElementsStr->arrayDirectoriesPtr,
            &dirElementsStr->currentArrayDirectoryMaxElements, 15);
      }

      // Add path string to struct
      dirElementsStr
          ->arrayDirectoriesPtr[dirElementsStr->currentArrayDirectoryElements] =
          newDir;
      dirElementsStr->currentArrayDirectoryElements += 1;

      // Recurse new path
      readDirAddFile(newDir, dirElementsStr);
    }

    entity = readdir(dir);
  };

  // Close read and free path to dir string
  closedir(dir);
  free((void *)pathToDir);

  return;
}

/*
  fetchFiles runs through the whole directory and stores all files' path
  into an array of strings pointers.
*/
void fetchFiles(struct dirElements *dirElementsStr) {
  // Recursively read from dir root
  readDirAddFile((const char *)&currentDir, dirElementsStr);
  return;
}

/*
  main execution
*/
int main() {
  // Track execution
  clock_t begin = clock();
  // printf() displays the string inside quotation
  printf("Scanning Directory files and paths\n\n");

  // Init filesStuct
  struct dirElements dirElementsStr = {
      .currentArrayDirectoryMaxElements = 15,
      .currentArrayDirectoryElements = 0,
      .currentArrayFileMaxElements = 15,
      .currentArrayFileElements = 0,
      .arrayFilesPtr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 15),
      .arrayDirectoriesPtr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 15)};

  // Fetch
  fetchFiles(&dirElementsStr);

  // Log and free found elements
  // Paths
  for (int i = 0; i < dirElementsStr.currentArrayDirectoryElements; ++i) {
    printf("Path Element number %i Found: %s\n", i,
           dirElementsStr.arrayDirectoriesPtr[i]);
    free((void *)dirElementsStr.arrayDirectoriesPtr[i]);
  };
  free((void *)dirElementsStr.arrayDirectoriesPtr);

  printf("\n");

  // Files
  for (int i = 0; i < dirElementsStr.currentArrayFileElements; ++i) {
    printf("File Element number %i Found: %s\n", i,
           dirElementsStr.arrayFilesPtr[i]);
    free((void *)dirElementsStr.arrayFilesPtr[i]);
  };
  free((void *)dirElementsStr.arrayFilesPtr);

  // Calculate execution Time
  clock_t end = clock();
  double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("\nScript took: %fs\n", time_spent);
  // End
  return 0;
}
```

If you run it in a big enough directory it will print out the old allocated directory and the new one, Strangely enough the new array has some of the first elements corrupted and the order is not kept, I have no idea why.

I tried using leaks but all memory is allocated and allocated without leaks, if you can suggest tools to debug memory allocations it will also help

Comment: When you print the newly enlarged array, what values do you expect new elements to have?

Comment: When you call `free(arrayPtr[i])`, what memory do you expect `newSizeArray[i]` to point at?

Comment: Correct Thank you. memcpy copies a x spaces memory over to another pointer but does not change the elements pointers, unless space in that position is not enough, but does, in that case, free space that is moved ver to another location?

Comment: I recommend drawing your data structure on a piece of paper. How does `arrayPtr` look like? (Spoiler: [something like this](https://overiq.com/media/uploads/memory-representation-of-array-of-pointers-1504599930139.png)). Now what does `memcpy` do? Draw the result.

Comment: In `IncreaseArraySize()` you try to print `totalNewMaxElements`, but they do not exist yet... The program is a bit overcomplex and these giant variable names are not helping either.